# Flash Memory block write counting & thresholding

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to solve this question:

> In a block storage system, new data is written in blocks. We are going
>   to represent the flash memory as one sequential array. We have a list
>   of block writes coming in the form of arrays of size 2: writes[i] =
>   [first_block_written, last_block_written].
>
> Each block has a rewrite limit. If rewrites on a block reach a certain
>   specified threshold we should run a special diagnostic.
>
> Given **blockCount** (an integer representing the total number of blocks),
>   **writes** (the list of block-write arrays of size 2), and **threshold**, your
>   task is to return the list of disjoint block segments, each consisting
>   of blocks that have reached the rewrite threshold. The list of block
>   segments should be sorted in increasing order by their left ends.
>
> Example
>
> For blockCount = 10, writes = [[0, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6]], and threshold
>   = 2, the output should be blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[2, 5]].
>
> - After the first write, the blocks 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 were written in
>     once
> - After the second write, the blocks 0, 1, 2 and 5 were written in
>     once, and the blocks 3 and 4 reached the rewrite threshold;
> - After the final write, the blocks 2 and 5 reached the rewrite threshold as well,
>     so the blocks that should be diagnosed are 2, 3, 4 and 5. Blocks 2, 3,
>     4 and 5 form one consequent segment [2, 5]. For blockCount = 10,
>     writes = [[0, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6]], and threshold = 3, the output
>     should be blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[3,
>     4]];
>
> For blockCount = 10, writes = [[3, 4], [0, 1], [6, 6]], and threshold
>   = 1, the output should be blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]].

I have come up with a correct naive solution here but it's too slow to pass the test cases:

```
def blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold):
    a = defaultdict(int)
    for (l, r) in writes:
        for i in range(l, r+1):
            a[i] += 1 

    start = None
    res = []
    for i in range(0, blockCount+1):
        if a[i] >=threshold:
            if start is None:
                start = i
        elif a[i] < threshold and start is not None:
            res.append([start, i-1])
            start = None
    return res
```

How do I optimize it to run faster?

Comment: The very wording of the problem statement may suggest use of [segment trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

Answer (score 3):

You can get an immediate speed-up by ditching the `defaultdict(int)`, and using a `bytearray(blockCount+1)` instead.  Both have roughly \$O(1)\$ lookup time, but the latter has a much smaller constant factor.  In the former, each `key` must be hashed, then binned, then a linear search through the bin is required to find the correct `key` entry, if it exists, and creating it if it does not.  In the latter, the `key` is a direct index to the required memory.

This demonstrates a better than 3x improvement of `bytearray` over `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def original():
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(1000000):
        d[i] += 1


>>> def using_bytearray():
    b = bytearray(1000000)
    for i in range(1000000):
        b[i] += 1


>>> timeit(original, number=100)
25.083420443999984
>>> timeit(using_bytearray, number=100)
7.779039941000008
```

Not only is the `bytearray` faster, it is also more memory efficient.  The `bytearray` uses just 57 bytes of overhead to store an array of 1 million bytes.  In contrast, the `defaultdict` weighs in at over 40x more memory ...

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
1000057
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
41943144
```

... but the real kicker is that is just the size of the dictionary's binning structures.  It excludes the size of all of the keys and values stored in the dictionary; those are harder to total as many small integers are interned and don't use additional storage allocation, and duplicate values may point to the same object.

**Note**: If `threshold` can exceed 255, you’d need to use `array.array` instead, with the appropriate type code for the largest rewrite count you’ll experience.

---

Of course, this is still the wrong approach.  With `writes = [[0, 999999], [1, 1000000]]`, it should be obvious that block 0 is written once, blocks 1 through 999999 are written twice, and block 1000000 is written once.  There is no need to loop through the million indices; we just need to consider the end-points of each range.

So just store the starting & ending points, and the number of times each has been seen.  With a sorted array of indices of where the transitions occur, you should be able to iterate over these transition points, and construct your diagnostic list.

Implementation left to student.

Bonus: it is possible use one simple `Dict[int,int]` structure to store both starting and ending counts, if you think about it the right way.

Comment: "You can get an immediate speed-up by ..." This seems to be pure conjecture. Python is a strange beast, and many of my assumptions, that are theorized like yours, have been wrong. Would you be willing to provide a timed plot to show that your statement is true? If, for some bizarre reason, `bytearray` were implemented in or partially in Python I can see both theoretically and logistically that a dictionary could be faster.

Comment: @Peilonrayz As you wish.

Comment: Thanks. Your timed tests are testing the performance of something different. Oh well, it's somewhat similar.